# Constant time algorithm given a partially filled tic-tac-toe board, determines if either player has won

Tags: algorithm, tic-tac-toe

I think I'm having trouble with the wording of this question, I don't understand how its possible to determine a winner of the board since Id have to use a for loop to determine the state of the board, and the for loop would be dependent on the size.

Comment: This question would need more detail: what does the algorithm exactly has to do, what are its inputs and outputs, and what is considered a single operation.

Comment: can you show us your implementation of the TicTacToe board or tell what is allowed to store as help

Comment: Strictly speaking, as the size of a Tic-Tac-Toe board is bounded by a constant, evaluation of the game via the  minmax algorithm can be done in constant time. Perhaps what is looked for is some kind of 'closed formula' (whatever this may be) for evaluation?

Comment: Are you going to have huge boards or something?  One way you could do this is amortize the cost of win calculation across moves by storing, along each row and column, the count of marks each player has made in that row or column and updating this after every move.  Then, to determine whether someone has won, iterate over these counts and check if any meet the required number.  This reduces the naive O(n^2) method to O(n).

Comment: This was all the information provided by the question. Ill check into the minmax algorithm.

Comment: Minimax will tell you what move to make *given a function that tells you the value of a board*; it won't tell you the value of the board.

Comment: There are fewer than 20K possible board configurations (not all of them valid), you could just do a table look up.

Comment: Im trying to determine if my teacher meant a board of any size, I think he mustve because otherwise what would be n for input size?

Comment: @JerryFederspiel And you can amortize costs even more by checking after each move whether the opponent already has at least 1 mark in the current row or column and throw them out of the collection there and then.

Comment: @Codor You won't need minimax to just determine whether someone has **already** won, just some loops, although it's possible that it's meant that we should determine whether we're in a game state that leads to guaranteed victory.

Comment: Why don't you go ask your teacher? We'd just be doing a lot of guessing and making assumptions if we try to answer it with the amount of information provided.

Comment: @Codor I assume you mean a for loop over a 2D array representing board state. Can you explain how this would still be constant time?

Comment: @Dukeling I agree the question needs clarification, I will update upon more information from the teacher.

Comment: @DanielKobe The iteration would be in constand time as the number of iterations is bounded by a constant; the loop `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` has a constant number (namely 3) of iterations.